# Is using a Service onStartCommand for multiple intents bad practice?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

I have a long-running foreground service which generates high priority notifications that require a yes/no button press in order to be dismissed.

The button presses are handled by addAction calls, where I must send in an Intent that will transmit the resulting button press.

Right now, I'm sending everything back to the foreground service, and the Intents are being picked up by the onStartCommand, like this:

```
override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {

    if (intent.action.equals("START_SERVICE")) {
        ...
    }

    if (intent.action.equals("STOP_SERVICE")) {
        ...
    }

    // etc....

}
```

My question is - is this ok? I know I can also set up a separate BroadcastReceiver to receive the Intents and communicate forward from there, but since I need to end up calling functions within the foreground service context, it seems like a bad idea to do all that. I wish the onStartCommand was named onReceive, I would feel better!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fairly standard for a non-bound service.  If the service is bound you'd generally use the binder instead, but that's a bit awkward via a notification.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The service is bound to MainActivity. Do you mean I should send intents to the MainActivity which then get passed to the foreground service (through the binding) and subsequently invoke the inner functions?

Comment: No.  Sending start commands is fine.  *If* the MainActivity was sending all the intents, I'd say that instead you should use the binder.  But notifications don't really make it easy to do that, so sending intents to the service directly is fine